# Google Places Autocomplete Can't load search results android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to implement the Google Places Autocomplete API sometimes I am able to get location list but sometimes I get "can't load search results" message. Can someone please help me with the issue?
added billing option and relevant keys to manifest allows me to type in an address but will not find results?

```
//Google services for maps and such
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.2'

public class ShopCart extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerItemTouchHelper {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference requests;
Place Orderaddress;

public TextView txtTotalPrice;
FButton btnPlace;
List<Order> carts = new ArrayList<>();
AdapterCart adapter;
RelativeLayout baseLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop_cart);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    requests = database.getReference("Requests");

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listCart);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    baseLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.baseLayout);

    txtTotalPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);
    btnPlace = (FButton)findViewById(R.id.btnOrder);

    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new DeleteFunction(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT,this);
    new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    btnPlace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //create request intent
            ShowAlertDialog();

        }

        private void ShowAlertDialog()
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder((ShopCart.this));
            alertDialog.setTitle("One More Thing");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Enter Your Delivery Address");

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View order_process = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_process,null); //may be issue
           // final MaterialEditText editAddress = (MaterialEditText)order_process.findViewById(R.id.editaddress);
            PlaceAutocompleteFragment editaddress = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_auto);
            editaddress.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((EditText)editaddress.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input))
                    .setHint("Enter Your address for order");
            ((EditText)editaddress.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input))
                    .setTextSize(14);
            editaddress.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                    Orderaddress = place;
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Status status) {
                    Log.e("Error",status.getStatusMessage());
                }
            });

    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google:android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="MY_KEY"/>
```

Comment: I've removed your API key from your question. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey